# Count row and get latest row by date from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count

I have 2 tables, Customer and CustomerActivity as showed in the picture below:

[image]

I want to output a table that:

- has all columns from Customer table where CustomerType = 'Existing Customer', plus 2 more columns:
- totalActivity (count activityID) - shows total activity number of each customer.
- latestActivity (max checkinTime) -  shows the most recent activity datetime

So far I have these 2 queries but I don't know how to combine/join and filter them to get what I need. Anyone can help with 1 query (and some explanation would be perfect)

```
SELECT customerId, firstName, birthDate, customerType 
FROM Customer 
WHERE Customer.customerType = 'Existing Customer'

SELECT t1.activityId, t1.checkinTime, t1.customerId
FROM CustomerActivity t1
inner join (
    SELECT customerId, max(checkinTime) as Lastest
    FROM CustomerActivity
    group by customerId
) t2 on t1.customerId = t2.customerId and t1.checkinTime = t2.Lastest
```

Answer (score 2):

You're actually close. Here is what your query should look like:

```
SELECT
    c.customerId,
    c.firstName,
    c.lastName,
    c.birthDate,
    c.customerType,
    ca.totalActivity,
    ca.latestActivity
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT 
        customerId, 
        latestActivity = MAX(checkinTime),
        totalActivity = COUNT(*)
    FROM CustomerActivity
    GROUP BY customerId
) ca
    ON ca.customerId = c.customerId
WHERE
    c.customerType = 'Existing Customer'
```

The subquery (inside the `INNER JOIN`) retrieves the total number of activities by using `COUNT(*)` and latest activity using `MAX(checkinTime)` of each customer. After that, you would want to join it to the `Customer` table on `customerId`. You then add a `WHERE` clause to filter for `'Existing Customer'` only.

Comment: As I noted in the comments of my answer, I believe this approach will be less efficient due to the subquery. I recommend looking at the execution plan of both, but I'd be willing to bet this approach will be aggregating the total activity and latest activity for every customer, whereas a direct join to the table will show you are only aggregating for the "existing" customers. The only thing I am not certain is if this will be optimized away, but I do not think it will. If you have 2 million customers of which only 200K are Existing, this could be a substantial difference in performance.

Comment: @ScottSmith, agree. I have no idea if the optimizer will be clever enough to optimize it in such a way that only the existing customer will be aggregated. I suggest the OP should look at the execution plan.

Comment: so which one is better for performance? (Note that each customer will be guaranteed to have at least 1 activity)

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding, you may want to see Scott Smith's answer for the alternative. We can't know for sure which is better. I suggest you do some testing.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it against an actual schema, but something like this should work (this approach will show customers even if they have no activity, simply change the left join to an inner join if you only want customers with activity):

```
SELECT c.CustomerID
    , c.FirstName
    , c.BirthDate
    , c.CustomerType
    , COUNT(ca.ActivityID) AS TotalActivity
    , MAX(ca.CheckinTime) AS MostRecentActivity
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN CustomerActivity ca ON c.CustomerID = ca.CustomerID
WHERE c.CustomerType = 'Existing Customer'
GROUP BY c.CustomerID
    , c.FirstName
    , c.BirthDate
    , c.CustomerType
```

Comment: I believe the other solutions proposed, due to the subquery within the join, would calculate the two activity aggregations for every customer in the system, and then afterward, filter them down to Existing Customers.  Whereas with this approach, you will only incur the overhead of those calculations for the Existing Customer records.

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want without `group by`, by using `row_number()` and window fu instead:

```
SELECT c.*, ca.numActivities, ca.activityId as LastActivity
FROM Customer c JOIN
     (select ca.*,
             count(*) over (partition by ca.CustomerId) as numActivities
             row_number() over (partition by ca.CustomerId order by checkinTime desc) as seqnum
      from CustomerActivity ca
     ) ca
     on c.customerId = ca.customerId and ca.seqnum = 1
WHERE c.customerType = 'Existing Customer';
```

This version will let you get whatever columns you like from the most recent activity row.

EDIT:

In your original question, I thought you wanted the latest activity.  If you just want the latest datetime, then aggregation works:

```
SELECT c.*, ca.numActivities, ca.lastActivityDateTime
FROM Customer c JOIN
     (select ca.*,
             count(*)  as numActivities
             max(checkinTime) as lastActivityDateTime
      from CustomerActivity ca
     ) ca
     on c.customerId = ca.customerId
WHERE c.customerType = 'Existing Customer';
```

Comment: Thanks for the both version, really helpful! Yes I want the latest by datetime, but can you explain a bit more about the `over (partition by ca.CustomerId)` part, what it does?

Comment: These are window functions.  A good place to start is with the documentation:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select c.customerId, c.firstName, c.lastName, c.birthDate, c.customerType, gca.latestCheckIn, gca.count
from customer as c, 
    (select ca.customerId, max(ca.checkInTime) as latestCheckIn, count(*) as checkinCount 
    from customerActivity as ca
    group by ca.customerId) as gca
where gca.customerId = c.customerId AND c.customerType = 'Existing Customer'
```

If you clarify more about customer with no activity, one can change the query to using left join